# How do I add float values to a byte array in C/Arduino?

Tags: arrays, c, arduino

I have the following code:

```
float a = 12.38;
float b = 24.38;
float c = 25.78;
float d = 20.00;

byte dataArray[4] = {a, b, c, d};

void setup() {
  
Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  
Serial.println(dataArray[0]);

}
```

The output I want to get is `12.38` but instead I get `12`. The float gets transformed into an integer. The reason why I am using a byte array is because I want to use the byte array as a message to a Master using I2C communication:

```
Wire.beginTransmission(slaveAddress); //address is queued for checking if the slave is present
  for (int i=0; i<4; i++)
  {
    Wire.write(dataArray[i]);  //data bytes are queued in local buffer
  }
  Wire.endTransmission();
```

The Master will then read and convert back to the original array using the following code:

```
#include<Wire.h>
#define slaveAddress 8  
byte dataArray[4];

void setup()
{
  Wire.begin(slaveAddress);
  Serial.begin(9600);
  //-----------------------------------
  Wire.onReceive(receiveEvent);
}

void loop()
{
Wire.onReceive(receiveEvent);
Serial.println(dataArray[1]);
}

void receiveEvent(int howmany) 
{
  for(int i=0; i<howmany; i++)
  {
    dataArray[i] = Wire.read();
  }
  
}
```

Comment: You should not use floating point at all on Arduino, because it's an incredibly slow legacy 8 bitter without a FPU. [Read this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/494924/6102).

Answer (score 6):

Float has size of 4 bytes. Therefore you need 4 bytes in your array to store each float. If you want to pass 4 floats you need 16 bytes

You can cast a pointer to `float` to a byte array:

```
   float a = 12.34
   byte dataArray[4] = {
      ((uint8_t*)&a)[0],
      ((uint8_t*)&a)[1],
      ((uint8_t*)&a)[2],
      ((uint8_t*)&a)[3]
   };
```

and make opposite operation on the receiver side:

```
    float a;
    ((uint8_t*)&a)[0] = dataArray[0];
    ((uint8_t*)&a)[1] = dataArray[1];
    ((uint8_t*)&a)[2] = dataArray[2];
    ((uint8_t*)&a)[3] = dataArray[3];
```

Comment: This would be the safest and most portable way, in C and C++ both. It's important to realize that we can go from `whatever_t` to `uint8_t` (character type), but often not the other way around.

Comment: This answer should be at the top of the list.

Answer (score 3):

Since a float is composed of 4 bytes, you cannot send one byte per value. You will need 4 bytes per value. So it will become something like this:

`byte dataArray[4] = {a0,a1,a1,a3, b0,b1,b2,b3, c0,c1,c2,c3, d0,d1,d2,d3};`

You will need a way to split your float into the four bytes. You can do this by using bit-operations, but... it's probably easier to use a Union:

```
union ByteFloatUnion{
  uint8_t byteformat[4];
  float floatformat;
}

ByteFloatUnion val;
val.floatformat = 1.23;

dataArray[0] = { val.byteformat[0], val.byteformat[1], val.byteformat[2], val.byteformat[3] } ;
```

Comment: You can't do this because Arduino is some C++ fiasco in disguise. I know this is tagged C, but the OP is actually using C++, where this code is undefined behavior.

Comment: @Lundin Are you sure? I don't use Arduino myself, but in this thread on the Arduino forums they suggest the same approach: https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=246654.0

Comment: @Lundin What does that have to do with not being able to use a union to convert floats to bytes? 
I use 8-bit AVR quite often myself (even though I wouldn't call myself an expert by any means), and I have no clue what you're hammering on
Yes, you should avoid using floats on 8-bitters without FPU at all cost. There's way more efficiënt ways to do things. But that wasn't the point here (even though it's a valid comment). 
OP essentially asked how to split an n-bit datatype into bytes. AFAIK using a union is one of the cleanest ways to do this.

Comment: Ok I misunderstood what you asked about. You cannot use union type punning in C++ because it is undefined behavior there, unlike C, which allows it. So the code posted invokes undefined behavior on Arduino. Unless you ditch the whole Arduino part and go bare metal AVR with a C compiler, then the code is fine.

Comment: @Lundin could you cite a source that says you shouldn't use unions on Arduino? 
Like I said, I'm not an Arduino user myself, but I can find a lot of Arduino-sources advising its usage. I can not find a source saying it's not allowed.

Comment: You can use unions but not type punning through unions (which makes them pretty useless). C++11 9.5 "In a union, at most one of the non-static data members can be active at any time, that is, the value of at most one of the non-static data members can be stored in a union at any time." Then further down: "Note: In general, one must use explicit destructor calls and placement new operators to change the active
member of a union. —end note ]"

Comment: However I believe GNU C++ has a non-standard extension that makes type punning well-defined.

Comment: @Lundin Yes, that's C++ in general, but are you sure that applies to Arduino? 
I find it hard to believe that several experienced Arduino users would advice to use Unions for this, while it would not work according to you?

Comment: In this specific case, it depends on compiler and compiler options used. But Arduino is through and through a collection of hobbyist quackery and dirty solutions.

Comment: I agree that Arduino is "through and through a collection of hobbyist quackery and dirty solutions" like you said. However, it has been a great way to introduce new people to the amazing world of electronics. 
Also, since it seems like the Arduino community recommends this way of solving this problem, I don't think it's a wrong answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
typedef union 
{
    union
    {
        float f;
        uint8_t b[sizeof(float)];
    }arr[4];
    uint8_t barray[sizeof(float)*4];
}FOUR_FLOATS_AND_BYTES_t;

void foo(void)
{
    float a = 12.38;
    float b = 24.38;
    float c = 25.78;
    float d = 20.00;

    FOUR_FLOATS_AND_BYTES_t f4 = {.arr[0].f = a, .arr[1].f = b, .arr[2].f = c, .arr[3].f = d};
}
```

`barray` member will contain all the 4 floats.

Comment: You can't do this because Arduino is some C++ fiasco in disguise. I know this is tagged C, but the OP is actually using C++, where this code is undefined behavior. Similarly they might not be able to use designated initializers, depending on C++ version.

Answer (score 0):

If you only need access to the bytes in order to send them, you can cast the pointer to float array to a pointer to byte array:

```cpp
float a = 12.38;
float b = 24.38;
float c = 25.78;
float d = 20.00;

float dataArray[4] = {a, b, c, d};

// ...

uint8_t *pData = (uint8_t *)dataArray;

for (int i=0; i<4 * sizeof(float); i++) {

    Wire.write(*pData++);  //data bytes are queued in local buffer
}

// or:

for (int i=0; i<4 * sizeof(float); i++) {

    Wire.write(pData[i]);  //data bytes are queued in local buffer
}
```

Just make sure both devices have the same [endianness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness).